# Play Framework ManyToMany Association Access

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1, ebean

I have the following two Models in my project:

```
@Entity
public class Reports extends Model{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Tags> tags;
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Tags extends Model{
    @Id
    public String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Reports reports;
```

Since these two entities have a @ManyToMany association, Play! automatically creates a table in my PostgreSQL database:

```
create table reports_tags (
  reports_id                     integer not null,
  tags_name                      varchar(255) not null,
  constraint pk_reports_tags primary key (reports_id, tags_name))
;
```

And here is a sample data of what the `reports_tags` should look like:

```
reports_id     tags_name
     1            pie
     1            bar
     1            line
     3            plot
     3            bar
     4            scattered
     4            plot
```

What I'm having problem is that I want to `find all reports where tags_name = 'bar'`

So with that "query" call, I should get back `reports` with `id` 1 and 3.

Using the conventional way of

```
Ebean.find(Reports.class)
    .where()
    .eq("tags_name", "bar")
    .findList()
```

won't work because there is no such fields with `tags_name` in the `Reports` model/table

I don't know what the code is to make that query call since my experience with Ebean is very little.

Comment: You should tag it with the language that you're using play

Comment: I apologize for that. I just tagged it. Using Java.

Comment: No need to apologize ! This is just to help for the format of the code and have a bit of more view if possible for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never worked with this Play! framework, but as far as I understand part of it contains a JPA implementation. In JPA when querying something you should refer to the java entity field name, not the column in the table itself, i.e. your query should be something like

```
Ebean.find(Reports.class)
.where()
.eq("tags.name", "bar")
.findList()
```

You can refer to the examples in the beginning of the javadoc [here](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Ebean.html)

Hope that helps

Comment: WOW!!!! That was it!! It is exactly like you said. I spent so much time on this thinking my database might need some rearranging. Man it sucks not knowing syntax! Thank you again.